# php pagination with break or continue

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I need to make a paging with this format:

`1 2 3 4 5 ... 205`

i use now this for loop:

```
$nav = '';
for($pageNum = 1; $pageNum <= $maxPage; $pageNum++)
{
   if ($pageNum == $p)
   {
   $nav .= '<li class=\"current\">$pageNum</li>';
   }
   else
   {
   $nav .= '<li><a href=\"?page=".$pageNum."\">$pageNum</a></li>';
   }
}
```

i need to use a php break or continue??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here there ara an example http://www.programacion.com/articulo/paginar_los_resultados_de_una_consulta_en_php_149